# The plugins `XXXXX` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, deprecated

i was trying to get my dependences using pub get, but i keep getting a bunch off errors.
And i'm stuck in these error.

I have tried   `flutter clean, flutter upgrade and flutter doctor` without any issue. Then i tried  `flutter pub cache repair` witch gave me this error `Failed to reactivate 1 package: - intl_utils pub finished with exit code 69`

Full error

```
The plugins `facebook_audience_network, flutter_statusbarcolor_ns, flutter_webview_plugin, 
notification_permissions, onesignal_flutter, sms_autofill` use a deprecated version of the 
Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures or future build failures, try to 
see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them 
since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin 
author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: 
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

MY `PUBSPEC.YAML`

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

facebook_audience_network: 1.0.0-nullsafety.0

flutter_statusbarcolor_ns: 0.3.0-nullsafety
flutter_webview_plugin: 0.4.0
notification_permissions: 0.5.0
onesignal_flutter: 3.2.0
sms_autofill: 2.0.1
...
```

Comment: Could you share your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: "since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs" So I think you are good with the current Flutter version to use, just make sure before you get the flutter next update that every one of these packages already got updated with the problem fix or you replaced it with another one.

Answer (score 18):

This is for the new flutter update.
There is nothing you can do.
Either use an other package or ask the package developer to fix the problem.
This error is after version 2.5 of the flutter.

Comment: ok, i'll do one of the options

Comment: use this package.  image_save: ^5.0.0

Answer (score 6):

This is after flutter v2.5 packge Error. Now Downgrade the flutter version [Version_list](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tags?after=2.5.0-5.2.pre). Now we look How to downgrade Flutter version. Following these Simple Steps.

Go to Terminal and Check `flutter --version`

then after Change the channel like this `flutter channel stable/dev/beta/master`

After Type `flutter downgrade <version>` (example: `flutter downgrade v1.2.1`)(You Can check verified [versions this place](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tags?after=2.5.0-5.2.pre))

Now Check `flutter --version` .

Now see Downgrade the version

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

That is because of the new flutter updates, but it won't stop you from building or running your code. or you could just switch to another package that can achieve the same task. Until the packages author update to v2 Android embedding

Answer (score 3):

You can fix the problem by following these instructions:

1- Close the `pubspec.yaml` file
2- Go to teminal
3- And run the following command

- `flutter pub upgrade --magor-version` or `flutter pub upgrade package_name`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command to run the project:-

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error from packages, the package developer should update something to the V2 Android embedding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem before. At that time I want to add this package agora_rtm: ^0.9.14, but then I got the same error as you stated above. What I did was just change the version number which is the latest one agora_rtm: ^1.1.0 then pub get and voila it works!

Answer (score 0):

The class `Jiffy` doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in `Jiffy.dart`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:jiffy/jiffy.dart';

extension TimestampExtension on Timestamp {
  String toFormattedString() {
    // Convert the Timestamp to a DateTime
    final dateTime = this.toDate();

    // Format the DateTime as a string
    return DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(dateTime);
    // You can customize the format string to match your preferred date and time format
  }

  String formattedDate() {
    DateTime timestamp = this.toDate();
    return DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(timestamp);
  }
}

extension TimeExtension on String {
  String? convertToTime12() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat.jm().format(dateFormat);
  }

  String? convertToTime24() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat.Hm().format(dateFormat);
  }

  String? convertToDate() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat.MMMd().format(dateFormat);
  }

  String? convertToMinute() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat.Hm().format(dateFormat);
  }

  String? convertToFullDate() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    return DateFormat.yMMMd().format(dateFormat);
  }

  String? differenceDay() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    final date = Jiffy(DateTime.now()).diff(dateFormat, Units.DAY).toString();
    if (date == "0") {
      return "Today";
    }
    if (date == "1") {
      return "Yesterday";
    }
    return "$date Days ago";
  }

    String? differenceHour() {
    DateTime dateFormat = DateTime.parse(this);
    final hours = Jiffy(DateTime.now()).diff(dateFormat, Units.HOUR).toString();
    return "$hours Hours ago";
  }

  String formattedTime() {
    if (this.isEmpty) {
      return ''; // Return empty string for null or empty input
    }
    DateTime timestamp =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.tryParse(this) ?? 0);
    return DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(timestamp);
  }

  String formattedDate() {
    if (this.isEmpty) {
      return ''; // Return empty string for null or empty input
    }
    DateTime timestamp =
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(int.tryParse(this) ?? 0);
    return DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(timestamp);
  }
}

extension TimestampFormatting on int {
  String formattedTimestamp() {
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(this);
    return DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(timestamp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Update the packages

- `facebook_audience_network`
- `flutter_statusbarcolor_ns`
- `flutter_webview_plugin`
- `notification_permissions`
- `onesignal_flutter`
- `sms_autofill`

to latest to solve the issue.

Answer (score -3):

may be u can change the version of the 'xxx' in pubspec.yaml
for exemple i have encountered a problem with 'Tflite'

tflite: ^1.1.2
then i changed it to
tflite: ^1.0.2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).