# Flutter. Lost connection to device erorr during running the app using vs code on the emulator

Tags: flutter

im trying to build an object detection app using flutter. i used tflite package v1.0.4 but the following error appeared:

> The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,
> consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

and then the following error message appeared during the running time:

> E/AndroidRuntime(23333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333): Process: com.example.examplerealtime, PID: 23333
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/~~2hFoR1hxWBPUrfqTqiwnWg==/com.example.examplerealtime-TWRy02G8hxydcAyR-5e49A==/base.apk)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.onAttachedToWindow(FlutterView.java:513)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> E/AndroidRuntime(23333):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Lost connection to device.

for the first error message i found a solution on the stack overflow that requires me to follow the steps on the following link:

> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration
> after doing the five steps here is how my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.examplerealtime">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="flutter_realtime_detection"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->



            <!-- Specify that the launch screen should continue being displayed -->
  <!-- until Flutter renders its first frame. -->
  <!-- <meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" /> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
           <meta-data
                android:name="flutterEmbedding"
                 android:value="2" />
    </application>
                              
</manifest>
```

and here is my MainActivity.java:

```
// MainActivity.java
package com.example.examplerealtime;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

}
```

i checked my internet connection and it is not the reason of the problem.
is the problem related to tflite package or i didn't change my AndroidManifest.xml file correctly?

Edit:
i granted all the required permissions and got the following error in the running time

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10254): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10254): Process: com.example.examplerealtime, PID: 10254
E/AndroidRuntime(10254): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/~~8UWBC8ZQqBgLMXftuoVKfA==/com.example.examplerealtime-YPMj52bhRZ1ktepHQ6j4GQ==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.onAttachedToWindow(FlutterView.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(10254):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:64003/hDzS4MkIvzQ=/
```

i also tried to uninstall and reinstall the app and the vs code but the above message appeared.

Answer (score 0):

This is because flutter has been updated but the author has not updated the package yet.
either ask the developer of the package to update it or use a similar package .
you can also fix this by downgrading flutter to a lower version

You can see more information on the following page:
[The plugins `XXXXX` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920646/the-plugins-xxxxx-use-a-deprecated-version-of-the-android-embedding)