# The plugin `flutter_webview_plugin` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding since no package 'flutter_webview_plugin' in pubspec.yaml file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I have upgraded the flutter version to the latest (3.7.7). when I upgrade, some dependencies also upgraded. but some of them are not compatible with null-safe. Now I upgraded all dependencies which are supported to null-safe versions.

Now occurred following error when I try to pub get

[image]

Since I'm not using 'flutter_webview_plugin' package anywhere in pubspec.yaml but pubspec.lock file have that package.

is there any solution to solve this issue without downgrading the flutter version?

Comment: add error message as a plane text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The plugins \`XXXXX\` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68920646/the-plugins-xxxxx-use-a-deprecated-version-of-the-android-embedding)